# How to Compare String of HashMap and arrange them?

Tags: android, string

Supose i have name `Mink,Mark,Aashis`. How do compare them and arrange them according to alphabetical order. `Collections.sort()` dont work for me.  Here i should have results `Aashis,Mark and Mark`.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("name", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
                mylist.add(map);

                 Collections.sort( mylist, new Comparator<HashMap<String,String>>(){                    

                    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> lhs,
                            HashMap<String, String> rhs) {
                            //how do i compare string name
                        return 0;

                    }
                 });
```

Comment: You've shown a *list* of maps, but your example just talks about 3 names. What's the mapping?

Comment: name is xml tag which i already parsed and list in listview also. I want to arrange that list according to name, id  etc. How do compare them now ?

Comment: don't return o just get your value from the hasmap using get method and compare it using compare().. Check my answer...

Comment: @captainpirate, If my answer solves your problem then please kindly mark it as Answer so that it helps others in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator(){

public int compare(HashMap<String, String> o1, HashMap<String, String> o2) {
        return (o1.get("name")).compareToIgnoreCase(o2.get("name"));
    }
```

Here "name" is the Key that you have provided at the time of insertion in the HashMap using put method.

***EXTRA***

If you want to parse double values then you can use the Double.parse() method.

**return Double.compare(o1.get(value1), o1.get(value2));**

**NOTE - The nice thing about this approach is that you then sort any object by any attribute or even a combination of attributes. For example if you have objects of type Person with an attribute income and dataOfBirth you could define different implementations of Comparator and sort the objects according to your needs.**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Is there any mistake here  `String s1=o1.get("score");
        String s2=o2.get("score");
        Double s1Value=Double.parseDouble(s1);
        Double s2Value=Double.parseDouble(s2);
        return Double.compare(s1Value, s2Value);`

It work for string but didnt work for double as i write code above .

Comment: why are you storing it in string. do like this...
double val1, val2;
val1 = Double.parseDouble(o1.get("score"));
val2 = Double.parseDouble(o2.get("score"));
return Double.compare(val1,val2);

Comment: What error you are getting? Because i didn't get any error i have used it in many times..

Comment: Event in double and integer i wrote the same code like :   
`return (lhs.get("accessibility").compareTo(rhs    .get("accessibility")));` it works fine.

Comment: This ` return (o1.get("name")).compareToIgnoreCase(o2.get("name"));` arrange the name in alphabetical order like a, b,c...z but what should i do to order in reverse like z,y......a ?

Answer (score 2):

try this code

insert values

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<String, String>();

            info.put("title", "gdfgdfgdfgdfggdfgfdgdgdgdffghfghfgh");
            info.put("time", "44:55");
            info.put("view", "54,353");

            list.add(info);

        }
```

get and compare

```
String title1 = ketan;



for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map = list.get(i);

        if(map.get("title")==title1);
                 {
                    ........
                    ......
                 }      
    }
```