# Sorting Double Data (distance) on ListView

Tags: android, sorting, listview

I've problem about sorting data from listview. I search in here and found about sorting String data. I need to sort Double data from my listView, I've same problem like this [Android: How to sort data for ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149994/android-how-to-sort-data-for-listview), and I found someone using this method for sorting String data : [How to Compare String of HashMap and arrange them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834849/how-to-compare-string-of-hashmap-and-arrange-them).

**My Code here**:

```
JSONArray tambalban = null;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listMotor = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new GetJSON().execute();
}

 public class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>{

@Override
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURL(url);
    try {
        tambalban = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MOTOR);

        for (int i = 0; i < tambalban.length(); i++){
            JSONObject mtr = tambalban.getJSONObject(i);

            String id_tb = mtr.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name_tb = mtr.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String address_tb = mtr.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
            String telp_tb = mtr.getString(TAG_TELP);
            String lat = mtr.getString(TAG_LAT);
            String lng = mtr.getString(TAG_LNG);

            double lat_tujuan = Double.parseDouble(lat);
            double lng_tujuan = Double.parseDouble(lng);
            double lat_asal = -7.781083333;
            double lng_asal = 110.4824833;

            double distance = hitungJarak (lat_asal, lng_asal, lat_tujuan, lng_tujuan);
            distance = RoundDecimal(distance, 2);
            String jarak = Double.toString(distance)+ " km";

            HashMap<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>();
            a.put(TAG_ID, id_tb);
            a.put(TAG_NAME, name_tb);
            a.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address_tb);
            a.put(TAG_TELP, telp_tb);
            a.put(TAG_LAT, lat);
            a.put(TAG_LNG, lng);
            a.put(TAG_DISTANCE, distance); 

            listMotor.add(a);

**Sorting Code**                
Collections.sort(listMotor, new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(HashMap<String, String> o1,
                        HashMap<String, String> o2) {

                    return Double.compare(o1.get(Double.parseDouble(TAG_DISTANCE)), o1.get(Double.parseDouble(TAG_DISTANCE))); // error
                    // return Double.compare(o1.get(value1), o1.get(value2)); **--> PREM answer, how to use it?**
                }                   
            });                         
        }           
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return listMotor;       
}


private double RoundDecimal(double distance, int i) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(distance);
    bd = bd.setScale(i, 6);         
    return bd.doubleValue();
}


private double hitungJarak(double lat_asal, double lng_asal,
        double lat_tujuan, double lng_tujuan) {

    double dist;
    double radius = 6371;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat_tujuan- lat_asal);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lng_tujuan - lng_asal);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat_asal)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat_tujuan))
            * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    double valueResult = radius * c;
    double km = valueResult/1;
    DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
    int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
    dist = radius * c;
    return dist;        
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listMotor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPostExecute(listMotor);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), listMotor,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAMA, TAG_ALAMAT, TAG_JARAK },
            new int[] { R.id.namatb, R.id.alamattb, R.id.jarak });
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}    
 }

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
}

 @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String pilih = getListAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            pilih,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          

    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailDaftar.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Selected", pilih);

    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

How to make **return Double.compare(o1.get(value1), o1.get(value2));** work, Any method that more simpler than parse distance from String to Double and Double to String again?

**Logcat Output**

```
02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578): Process: com.maps.paktebe, PID: 2578
02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "0.34 km"
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at com.maps.paktebe.Motor$AmbilDataJSON$1.compare(Motor.java:98)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at com.maps.paktebe.Motor$AmbilDataJSON$1.compare(Motor.java:1)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:185)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2023)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1883)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at com.maps.paktebe.Motor$AmbilDataJSON.doInBackground(Motor.java:92)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at com.maps.paktebe.Motor$AmbilDataJSON.doInBackground(Motor.java:1)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 02-10 10:58:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(2578):    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to parse the value you get out of the map, instead of parsing the input. Update your compare like this:

```
@Override
public int compare(HashMap<String, String> o1,
                    HashMap<String, String> o2) {
    return Double.compare(Double.parseDouble(o1.get(TAG_DISTANCE)), Double.parseDouble(o2.get(TAG_DISTANCE)));
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've try with your code, but still getting error, I update logcat output. Any ideas?

Comment: ohh, I got it, this error because I add "km" in distance. Thanks mate, it's work